# Swift: Not Return to English Version after translate to Arabic

Tags: ios, swift, localization, right-to-left

i want to localize my apps between English and Arabic version included RTL. but it not return to English Version with left to right after translate to Arabic, it just repeats to Arabic version when i click navigation item UIButton, also navigation item flag not show properly it is just repeating Arabic flag.

// here is my code

```
import UIKit

import Foundation



// homeCollectionViewController

class HomeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    let navLanguageBtn = UIButton()

    static var language = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupHomeNavBarBtn()

    }

    // NavigationBar
    func setupHomeNavBarBtn() {


        navLanguageBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CollectionViewSize.width / 15, height: CollectionViewSize.width / 15)
        navLanguageBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, CollectionViewSize.width / 60, 0)
        navLanguageBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arab_flag")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        navLanguageBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        navLanguageBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navLanguageBtnClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        let navLanguageBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navLanguageBtn)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([ navLanguageBtnItem], animated: true)

    }


    // ButtonClick
    public func navLanguageBtnClick(){


        if (navLanguageBtn.isSelected == true)
        {
            print("language btn click true English flag")


            navLanguageBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "english_flag")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: UIControlState.normal)
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft



            navLanguageBtn.isSelected = false

            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ar-SA", ofType: "lproj")
            let bundal = Bundle.init(path: path!)! as Bundle




            HomeCollectionViewController.language = "ar"



            navigationItem.title = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "home", value: nil, table: nil)

            SecondHomeCell.newProductTrans = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "newProduct", value: nil, table: nil)
            SecondHomeCell.populerStoriesTrans = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "populerStories", value: nil, table: nil)


            let navController: UINavigationController? = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let control = HomeCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

            navController?.pushViewController(control, animated: true)

            let AR_POST_PARAMETERS = ["language": HomeCollectionViewController.language]

            self.secondHomeCell?.secondHomeCellDataLoad(POST_PARAMETERS: AR_POST_PARAMETERS as! Dictionary<String, String>)

        }
        else
        {

            print("language btn click true arabic flag")
            navLanguageBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arab_flag")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: UIControlState.selected)
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            // UIView.appearance().transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            navLanguageBtn.isSelected = true

            // self.lblCountryName.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj")
            let bundal = Bundle.init(path: path!)! as Bundle


            //home
            HomeCollectionViewController.language = "en"

            navigationItem.title = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "home", value: nil, table: nil)

            SecondHomeCell.newProductTrans = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "newProduct", value: nil, table: nil)
            SecondHomeCell.populerStoriesTrans = bundal.localizedString(forKey: "populerStories", value: nil, table: nil)

            let navController: UINavigationController? = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let control = HomeCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

            navController?.pushViewController(control, animated: true)

            let AR_POST_PARAMETERS = ["language": HomeCollectionViewController.language]

            self.secondHomeCell?.secondHomeCellDataLoad(POST_PARAMETERS: AR_POST_PARAMETERS as! Dictionary<String, String>)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of time changing language on the fly. The bar items cannot be change without relaunching the app (the arrow of the navigation also flipped) in my app I'm showing an alert view that tells the user that some of the components are changing only after app restart

Comment: And about the English.... I don't think the English strings are in "en" folder.. Check if it's in "Base" folder

Comment: @Yitzchak i put language = "" instant of "en" but still same problem. it just repeating Arabic and right to left.

Comment: Check the folders and set the proper path to the bundle... I think it's in a folder named "Base"... Don't guess, just check!

Comment: put a breakpoint after this line: `print("language btn click true English flag")` try to touch the button couple of times. Are you able to enter there ?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the language of application, from a button click within the appliaction, i suggest you to ask the user to relaunch the application, for the change to happen.

In my application, i am changing the language like this.

```
//On Button click:

if applicationLanguage() == "ar"  {
                    setApplicationLanguage(languageCode: "en-US")
                } 
else if applicationLanguage() == "en"  {
                setApplicationLanguage(languageCode: "ar")
            }




func applicationLanguage() -> String
    {
        let languages : NSArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! NSArray
        let selectedLanguage : String = languages[0] as! String
        return selectedLanguage.components(separatedBy: "-").first!
    }

func setApplicationLanguage(languageCode : String)
    {
        // Show Alert to restart the application. Present it in your view controller.



        UserDefaults.standard.set([languageCode], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

The user should manually quit the application, for the change to happen.

Comment: unresolved identifier `applicationLanguage`, `SVUtility` and    `appDelegate` in this code `appDelegate.window?.topMostWindowController()?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: applicationLanguage() is just a custom function to get the current language of the application. Forget about taking the topmost view controller, you can present the lert in your view controller

Comment: and "SVUtility"

Comment: It is a global class used in my project.I have setApplicationLanguage() and applicationLanguage() methods defined in that class, so that i can access from any place in my project.

Comment: Friend! after use your code. it automatically come RTL. it never show LTR after click Button

Comment: After the button click, did you quit the app and restarted again?

Comment: For each click of the button to change the language, the user should manually quit the app and restart again.

Comment: yes i did. still button is not work. friend. i am new of iOS. so can you write full code please?.   there will be button in navigationItem. when i click navigationItem's Button it will change language and RTL.

Comment: if it is possible to align the labels by using auto layout than align them to RTL. label.alignment = .right

Comment: than it will show text according to the frame size. but i think u should use label alignment to RTL by using checks "if eng LTR else RTL alignment".